# how to resolve number format Exception?

Tags: java

i used the below code

```
int a= Integer.parseInt(holders);
```

Exception is

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8,852,671"
```

Comment: Don't use comma's in your number, it cannot handle that

Comment: Not sure what result you want to achieve. It should not have `,` in them if you want to successfully parse them. or place that code in a try catch to handle the exception in any other way.

Comment: @Sachin our developers used , and "" i need only number how to get that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(holders.replace(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the number format,

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).parse(holders);
```